# Retrieving list of all online users using Django-online-users

Tags: python, django

I would like to retrieve a list of all users online on my, online meaning they have carried out some sort of activity on the app over the last 2 minutes.

I am noticing however, that my list only shows people who have logged in as an admin (atleast from what I am observing).

I am using the package `django-online-users` for this

I created a view with a queryset that would retrieve all online users who have carried out some activity on the app

```
class OnlineUsers(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = online_users.models.OnlineUserActivity.get_user_activities(timedelta(seconds=120))
    serializer_class = OnlineUsersSerializer
```

My OnlineUsersSerializer class:

```
class OnlineUsersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

This is my profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile/%Y/%m/%d',
                                    default='media/placeholder.png',
                                    blank=False,
                                    null=False)
    #we are hooking create_user_profile and save_user profile methods to the User model whenever a save event occurs. This kind of signal is called post_save
    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()
```

I created an API end-point that I would use to retrieve all online users from my React app:

```
path('online_users',OnlineUsers.as_view({'get':'list'}), name='online_users'),
```

Regardless of whether I login with a different user, I am only able to see one user (my admin account).

**UPDATE**

Based on the top answer I received this is what I tried:

```
class OnlineNowMixin:
    def initial(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
        user = request.user
        if not user.is_authenticated:
            return
        online_users.models.OnlineUserActivity.update_user_activity(user)
```

I added this class to all my viewsets:

```
class OnlineUsers(OnlineNowMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
...
class UserViewSet(OnlineNowMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
...
class UpdateProfileView(OnlineNowMixin, generics.UpdateAPIView):
...
class ProgrammingChallengeView(OnlineNowMixin, ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
...
class GetAllUsers(OnlineNowMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
...
```

However, the API end point I created still only shows users who logged as opposed to user who have been logged in through authentication (ie. received an access & refresh token).

This is what i am using for authentication:

```
class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)
        token['username'] = user.username
        token['first_name'] = user.first_name
        token['last_name'] = user.last_name
        token['country'] = user.profile.country
        token['city'] = user.profile.city
        token['bio'] = user.profile.bio
        token['photo'] = json.dumps(str(user.profile.profile_pic))
        return token

class CustomTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

Comment: I see you are using DRF, what kind of authentication classes do you use? Out of the built in ones probably the only one that will work with you use is the session based one.

Answer (score 0):

Your users aren't processed as online by the middleware probably because you are using Django Rest Framework (DRF). DRF performs the authentication on the view layer, out of the various builtin authentication classes only `SessionAuthentication` will have the user authenticated at the middleware level.

What you can do to solve this problem is create a mixin to be used by **all your views / viewsets**. This mixin should override the [`initial` method](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#initialself-request-args-kwargs) and do what the `OnlineNowMiddleware` from `django-online-users` does:

```
from online_users.models import OnlineUserActivity


class OnlineNowMixin:
    def initial(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
        user = request.user
        if not user.is_authenticated:
            return

        OnlineUserActivity.update_user_activity(user)


class OnlineUsers(OnlineNowMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
```

Comment: Still having the same issue with this

Comment: @Emm you have to use that mixin with **all** your views / viewsets.

Comment: Yes, I added a that mixin to all my views, updating my question with the changes to show you what I did